# Swift Change UIView Image

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiview, uiimageview

I am trying to make a basic game for iOS10 using swift 3 and scenekit. In one part of my games code I have a function that adds fishes to the screen, and gives each one a certain tag so i can find them later:

```
let fish = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(fishsize.0), height: CGFloat(fishsize.1)))
fish.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
fish.center = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(fishsize.0) * -0.6, y: pos)
fish.animationImages = fImg(Fishes[j].size, front: Fishes[j].front)
fish.animationDuration = 0.7
fish.startAnimating()

fish.tag = j + 200
self.view.insertSubview(fish, belowSubview: big1)
```

What I would like is to be able to, at a certain point, recall the fish and

- Change the images shown, and
- Stop the animation.

Is this possible? I've been trying it with `var fish = view.viewWithTag(killer+200)!` but from this I can't seem to change any image properties of the new variable `fish`.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast the `UIView` to `UIImageView` like this.

```
if let fish = view.viewWithTag(killer+200) as? UIImageView {
    //Perform your action on imageView object
}
```

Comment: So simple, thanks a bunch. Works like a charm! Stupid of me for not realizing this earlier.